# css postioning with images and text at top?

Tags: html, css, image

i have this `li` list which displays an image with the username right next to it: but the username is at the bottom, i want it to be at the top:

just like this:

[image]

the code i have is at http://www.jsfiddle.net/RpCUV/ with an illustration of my current code,

i know this is a simple questions, but i'm new to this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align: top` to the CSS for the `<img>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Just glancing over I would recommend floating the image and adjusting line-height

```
  li img{float:left;}
  li {line-height: 1.5 ish;}
```